# Error 400 on Put request to a RestFull webService

Tags: angularjs, web-services, put

I need to call a Web Service to get some data, but when i use this code :

```
app.controller('Hello', function($scope, $http) {

var config = {
  headers:  {
        "loginName": 'opzudecche',
        "password" : "****"
    }
};

$http.put("WEBSERVICEURL", config).then(function(response) {
  $scope.greeting = response.data;
});



});
```

It continues to return me an error 400... where I'm wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first check service is working then use this code

```
var app = angular.module('Hello', '$http', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $http({
    method: "PUT",
    url: "WEBSERVICEURL",
    headers: {
      'loginName': 'opzudecche',
      'password': "****"
    },
  }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
    $scope.greeting = response.data;
  }, function myError(response) {
    $scope.error = response.data;
  });

});
```